# Load pretrained eigen recognizer instead of retraining each time

Tags: python, opencv, eigen

I currently have a python script running openCV based face detection (Haar cascade) and recognition (Eigen recognizer) on the raspberry pi. This is working well and I am happy with the results, once it is all up and running.

However, training the Eigen recognizer takes quite some time (in excess of a minute) and is happening every time I run the script.

I was wondering if there was a way to train the Eigen recognizer in a separate script, saved the trained recognizer and then load the pre-trained recognizer instead.

Only when the training data was updated, the recognizer would be retrained.

I know this can be achieved by neural networks, however I don't think I know quite enough about the Eigen method.

If this is possible, some sample code, or a link to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what kind of an "object" is a face recognizer? Maybe it (or the trained data itself) can be saved with `cv::FileStorage` : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html

Comment: The recognizer is stored as an XML, so that link was right on the money, Using it as guidance I have just implemented something similar to that, but was hit with an end of stream error. I think this might be because the "labels" segment of the recognizer does not export with it.

Either way the link is a very useful resource, thanks!

Comment: sure that's possible. just use the [FaceReconizer's load and save](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html#FaceRecognizer%20:%20public%20Algorithm) methods. (and probably store as myfaces.yml.gz, else the load time will get close to the time needed for retraining)

Comment: Hey Berak, thanks I actually did just that.

I didn't realise it would be that easy! took me a little while to find the documentation on it.
If you submit that as an answer I'll happily accept as answer.

Cheers!